Kali Linux terminal autocomplete breaks hitting tab, or paste from clipboard and pressing left arrow
If I paste a command from the clipboard and hit left arrow to change the command the command changes it will duplicate the first word of the command, however if you use the cursor to it, it starts at the second word so everthing is shifted.
Same happens if I type a command from history, and then hit tab, you will see the same double word.
The shell is zsh:
# echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh

# set | grep -i zsh_
HISTFILE=/root/.zsh_history
ZSH_ARGZERO=/usr/bin/zsh
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS=( forward-char end-of-line vi-forward-char vi-end-of-line vi-add-eol )
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_CLEAR_WIDGETS=( history-search-forward history-search-backward history-beginning-search-forward history-beginning-search-backward history-substring-search-up history-substring-search-down up-line-or-beginning-search down-line-or-beginning-search up-line-or-history down-line-or-history accept-line copy-earlier-word )
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_COMPLETIONS_PTY_NAME=zsh_autosuggest_completion_pty
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_EXECUTE_WIDGETS=(  )
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE='fg=#999'
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_IGNORE_WIDGETS=( 'orig-*' beep run-help set-local-history which-command yank yank-pop 'zle-*' )
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ORIGINAL_WIDGET_PREFIX=autosuggest-orig-
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_PARTIAL_ACCEPT_WIDGETS=( forward-word emacs-forward-word vi-forward-word vi-forward-word-end vi-forward-blank-word vi-forward-blank-word-end vi-find-next-char vi-find-next-char-skip )
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_STRATEGY=( history )
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_USE_ASYNC=''
ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT=toplevel
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_DIRS_BLACKLIST=(  )
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=( main brackets pattern )
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_PATTERNS=( )
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_REGEXP=( )
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_REVISION=debian/0.7.1-2
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES=( [arg0]='fg=cyan' [assign]=none [autodirectory]='fg=green,underline' [back-dollar-quoted-argument]='fg=magenta,bold' [back-double-quoted-argument]='fg=magenta,bold' [back-quoted-argument]=none [back-quoted-argument-delimiter]='fg=blue,bold' [bracket-error]='fg=red,bold' [bracket-level-1]='fg=blue,bold' [bracket-level-2]='fg=green,bold' [bracket-level-3]='fg=magenta,bold' [bracket-level-4]='fg=yellow,bold' [bracket-level-5]='fg=cyan,bold' [command-substitution]=none [command-substitution-delimiter]='fg=magenta,bold' [commandseparator]='fg=blue,bold' [comment]='fg=black,bold' [cursor]=standout [cursor-matchingbracket]=standout [default]=none [dollar-double-quoted-argument]='fg=magenta,bold' [dollar-quoted-argument]='fg=yellow' [double-hyphen-option]='fg=green' [double-quoted-argument]='fg=yellow' [global-alias]='fg=green,bold' [globbing]='fg=blue,bold' [history-expansion]='fg=blue,bold' [line]='' [named-fd]=none [numeric-fd]=none [path]=bold [path_pathseparator]='' [path_prefix_pathseparator]='' [precommand]='fg=green,underline' [process-substitution]=none [process-substitution-delimiter]='fg=magenta,bold' [rc-quote]='fg=magenta' [redirection]='fg=blue,bold' [reserved-word]='fg=cyan,bold' [root]=standout [single-hyphen-option]='fg=green' [single-quoted-argument]='fg=yellow' [suffix-alias]='fg=green,underline' [unknown-token]=underline )
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_VERSION=0.7.1-2_debian
ZSH_NAME=zsh
ZSH_PATCHLEVEL=debian/5.9-6
ZSH_SUBSHELL=1
ZSH_VERSION=5.9
_ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ASYNC_FD=13
_ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_BIND_COUNTS=( [accept-and-hold]=1 [accept-and-infer-next-history]=1 [accept-and-menu-complete]=1 [accept-line]=1 [accept-line-and-down-history]=1 [accept-search]=1 [argument-base]=1 [auto-suffix-remove]=1 [auto-suffix-retain]=1 [autosuggest-capture-completion]=1 [backward-char]=1 [backward-delete-char]=1 [backward-delete-word]=1 [backward-kill-line]=1 [backward-kill-word]=1 [backward-word]=1 [beginning-of-buffer-or-history]=1 [beginning-of-history]=1 [beginning-of-line]=1 [beginning-of-line-hist]=1 [bracketed-paste]=1 [capitalize-word]=1 [clear-screen]=1 [complete-word]=1 [copy-prev-shell-word]=1 [copy-prev-word]=1 [copy-region-as-kill]=1 [deactivate-region]=1 [delete-char]=1 [delete-char-or-list]=1 [delete-word]=1 [describe-key-briefly]=1 [digit-argument]=1 [down-case-word]=1 [down-history]=1 [down-line]=1 [down-line-or-history]=1 [down-line-or-search]=1 [emacs-backward-word]=1 [emacs-forward-word]=1 [end-of-buffer-or-history]=1 [end-of-history]=1 [end-of-line]=1 [end-of-line-hist]=1 [end-of-list]=1 [exchange-point-and-mark]=1 [execute-last-named-cmd]=1 [execute-named-cmd]=1 [expand-cmd-path]=1 [expand-history]=1 [expand-or-complete]=1 [expand-or-complete-prefix]=1 [expand-word]=1 [forward-char]=1 [forward-word]=1 [get-line]=1 [gosmacs-transpose-chars]=1 [history-beginning-search-backward]=1 [history-beginning-search-forward]=1 [history-incremental-pattern-search-backward]=1 [history-incremental-pattern-search-forward]=1 [history-incremental-search-backward]=1 [history-incremental-search-forward]=1 [history-search-backward]=1 [history-search-forward]=1 [infer-next-history]=1 [insert-last-word]=1 [kill-buffer]=1 [kill-line]=1 [kill-region]=1 [kill-whole-line]=1 [kill-word]=1 [list-choices]=1 [list-expand]=1 [magic-space]=1 [menu-complete]=1 [menu-expand-or-complete]=1 [menu-select]=1 [neg-argument]=1 [overwrite-mode]=1 [pound-insert]=1 [push-input]=1 [push-line]=1 [push-line-or-edit]=1 [put-replace-selection]=1 [quote-line]=1 [quote-region]=1 [quoted-insert]=1 [read-command]=1 [recursive-edit]=1 [redisplay]=1 [redo]=1 [reset-prompt]=1 [reverse-menu-complete]=1 [select-a-blank-word]=1 [select-a-shell-word]=1 [select-a-word]=1 [select-in-blank-word]=1 [select-in-shell-word]=1 [select-in-word]=1 [self-insert]=1 [self-insert-unmeta]=1 [send-break]=1 [set-mark-command]=1 [spell-word]=1 [split-undo]=1 [toggle_oneline_prompt]=1 [transpose-chars]=1 [transpose-words]=1 [undefined-key]=1 [undo]=1 [universal-argument]=1 [up-case-word]=1 [up-history]=1 [up-line]=1 [up-line-or-history]=1 [up-line-or-search]=1 [vi-add-eol]=1 [vi-add-next]=1 [vi-backward-blank-word]=1 [vi-backward-blank-word-end]=1 [vi-backward-char]=1 [vi-backward-delete-char]=1 [vi-backward-kill-word]=1 [vi-backward-word]=1 [vi-backward-word-end]=1 [vi-beginning-of-line]=1 [vi-caps-lock-panic]=1 [vi-change]=1 [vi-change-eol]=1 [vi-change-whole-line]=1 [vi-cmd-mode]=1 [vi-delete]=1 [vi-delete-char]=1 [vi-digit-or-beginning-of-line]=1 [vi-down-case]=1 [vi-down-line-or-history]=1 [vi-end-of-line]=1 [vi-fetch-history]=1 [vi-find-next-char]=1 [vi-find-next-char-skip]=1 [vi-find-prev-char]=1 [vi-find-prev-char-skip]=1 [vi-first-non-blank]=1 [vi-forward-blank-word]=1 [vi-forward-blank-word-end]=1 [vi-forward-char]=1 [vi-forward-word]=1 [vi-forward-word-end]=1 [vi-goto-column]=1 [vi-goto-mark]=1 [vi-goto-mark-line]=1 [vi-history-search-backward]=1 [vi-history-search-forward]=1 [vi-indent]=1 [vi-insert]=1 [vi-insert-bol]=1 [vi-join]=1 [vi-kill-eol]=1 [vi-kill-line]=1 [vi-match-bracket]=1 [vi-open-line-above]=1 [vi-open-line-below]=1 [vi-oper-swap-case]=1 [vi-pound-insert]=1 [vi-put-after]=1 [vi-put-before]=1 [vi-quoted-insert]=1 [vi-repeat-change]=1 [vi-repeat-find]=1 [vi-repeat-search]=1 [vi-replace]=1 [vi-replace-chars]=1 [vi-rev-repeat-find]=1 [vi-rev-repeat-search]=1 [vi-set-buffer]=1 [vi-set-mark]=1 [vi-substitute]=1 [vi-swap-case]=1 [vi-undo-change]=1 [vi-unindent]=1 [vi-up-case]=1 [vi-up-line-or-history]=1 [vi-yank]=1 [vi-yank-eol]=1 [vi-yank-whole-line]=1 [visual-line-mode]=1 [visual-mode]=1 [what-cursor-position]=1 [where-is]=1 )
_ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_BUILTIN_ACTIONS=( clear fetch suggest accept execute enable disable toggle )
_ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_CHILD_PID=3790665
_ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_PRIOR_BUFFER=''
_ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_PRIOR_CURSOR=0
_zsh_highlight__highlighter_brackets_cache=(  )
_zsh_highlight__highlighter_main_cache=( '0 3 fg=cyan' '4 5 fg=blue,bold' '6 10 fg=cyan' '11 13 fg=green' '14 18 none' )
_zsh_highlight__highlighter_pattern_cache=(  )
_zsh_highlight_main__command_type_cache=( [set]=builtin )
precmd_functions=( _zsh_highlight_main__precmd_hook _zsh_autosuggest_start )
preexec_functions=( _zsh_highlight_preexec_hook )
zsh_eval_context=( toplevel )
zsh_highlight__pat_static_bug=false
zsh_scheduled_events

And PS1:
# set | grep PS1
PS1=$'%F{%(#.blue.green)}\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-L\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-@\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-@${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-@}${VIRTUAL_ENV:+($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV))\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-@}(%B%F{%(#.red.blue)}%n\M-c\M-\t\M-?%m%b%F{%(#.blue.green)})-[%B%F{reset}%(6~.%-1~/\M-b\M-\C-@\M-&/%4~.%5~)%b%F{%(#.blue.green)}]\n\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-T\M-b\M-\C-T\M-\C-@%B%(#.%F{red}#.%F{blue}$)%b%F{reset} '



that looks like your shell comes with a plugin like oh-my-zsh or oh-my-bash or maybe just powerlevel10k? We don't know which shell you're using, and which things it loads in its initialization, can you check that for us and add the info by editing your question, please?

Please [edit] your question and tell us i) what shell you are using and ii) the value of PS1 if your shell is bash, zsh etc, and whatever the equivalent is if your shell is something else.

Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for help formatting your posts (I fixed it now, don't worry).

That PS1 seems really complex. Are you sure you want such a thing on a Kali system? Kali is a professional tool after all, it seems odd to have such a setup there. What are all those \M?

This may not be the actual fix, but it works.
If you change the kali-terminal prompt to oneline, this issue goes away.
Run:
kali-tweaks
Then go to Shell & Prompt then Configure Prompt move cursor to One Line and press space then <Apply> then <Back> then <Quit>.
Reboot or type this to take into affect immediately:
source ~/.zshrc

I noticed that this was happening on some of my kali machines but not all. The difference I noticed between them was the locale. On the kali machines that had the tab completion issue it was set to a posix locale

On the kali machines that didn't have the tab completion issue the locale was set to en_US.UTF-8

I used the following command to update the locale. localectl was erroring
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE

